# How to make 3 divs with scaleable fullsize background images

Tags: css, image, html, background

I want to make a single page site, so that you have to scroll down to view the content. I have 3 different content divs. Each div should have a different background image wich should scale according to the size of the browser while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image.
hope its a bit clear what im trying to do?

This is the css i currently have :

```
.div1 {
height: 927px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(bg3.jpg);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
.div2 {
height: 927px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(bg1.jpg);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
.div3 {
height: 927px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(bg2.jpg);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

And this is the html :

```
<body>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>

</body>
```

As you can see it will not scale each div background image to the correct size of the browser. Anyone got a good solution to do this?

Comment: this will help only for new browsers: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ else have a look at http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ (it not as easy as it sounds, you need javascript to keep ratio for older browsers!)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but your links are about fullsize background images for entire page. I want to have 3 different background images for 3 different divs on 1 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is looking good for the attemp. It's likely that the background of your divs keep scrolling while the user is browsing down the page. The background behaves like position:fixed; element. To stop that, just add this:

```
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
```

I've been confused by the static height of the div containing the background image. I thught you just wanted to adjust the width according to the browser window.

It's a bit hacky, but you could try to do this:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

.div1,.div2,.div3
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
    position: absolute;
}

.div1
{
    top: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

.div2
{
    top: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.div3
{
    top: 200%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

See Example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/bah93/

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i tried it but the images dont show up (i added the background images to div1, div2 and div3 in the css), i just get a white page.

Comment: Did you alter your default style? You need to add: width: 100%;. I've updated my anweser with a fiddle

Comment: Hi Nico, yes its working now with this code, but try putting background images in your divs, and then scale your browser width/height, and you will see that the images get stretched.

Comment: Here is my fiddle and i don't see images stretched? http://fiddle.jshell.net/bah93/2/ Please make a fiddle your self if the problem persists. Btw. Do you mean streched or distorted? Of course the image will be streteched with the size of the browser. But the resultion should be kept. If you don't want it to become wider or smaller, use min-width, max-width on div1-3

Comment: If you do not want that the image can be cropped, you may also use:  `background-size: contain;` But that will not always fill the certain div.

Comment: Hi Nico, now with your new code it works perfectly, just the way i wanted. Many thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently.I had to put 5 backgrounds to each div according to screen size..

Dont worry Let's Try this..

You need js/jquery to get results Or I tooks jquery for setting div height exact to screen height..

Code :
**HTML**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="page one"></div>
  <div class="page two"></div>
  <div class="page three"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page{ height: 927px;
       width: 100%;
       -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
       -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
       -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
       background-size: 100% 100%;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center center; 
      }
.page.one {background-image: url(bg1.jpg);}
.page.two {background-image: url(bg2.jpg);}
.page.three {background-image: url(bg3.jpg);}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page').css('height',window.innerHeight)
})
```

Edited Part : 
Put This in your Header And Chill :)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page').css('height',window.innerHeight)
})
</script>
</head>
```

Hope This helps you..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reaction. I want to try your solution, but im not familiar on how to create the jquery part. Do i have to put the code in a .js file? i tried it but it gives syntaxx error. Hope you can help me?

Comment: Try This I have Edited :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Krunal. I tried it and dreamweaver still gives me a syntax error on the first line of your script, but i tried it anyway and it seems like it scales the image height to the browser size, so thats good, but the aspect ratio of the image is not ok. The image is stretched out. For example, if i use a 1920x927 image as a background, and i use your script on a screen with 1200x1024 resolution, it stretches the height so the image looks stretched out.